# Why does this PHP fgetcsv() display only certain parts of the csv?

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I have this PHP:

```
$handle = fopen($_FILES["csvfile"]["tmp_name"], "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 5000, ",", '"')) !== FALSE) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "<pre>";
}

<form method="post">
<input type="file" name="csvfile">
<input type="submit>
```

The CSV is provided by an html `<input type="file">`. Right now it is printing out arrays that are only the first value and a comma or each row instead of printing out an array of eleven values of each row. I got it to do the right thing, but somehow messed up my code and can't figure out what I did.

Here is an example of the CSV:

```
"lorem","ipsum","dolor","sit","amet","consectetuer","adipiscing","elit","sed ","diam","nonummy",
```

Comment: are you sure you specified the separators as you should? post a sample of the input data also

Comment: what does your csv file look like? Did you see if it's formatted properly?

Comment: @nikc What's wrong with the title?

Comment: @chromedude: A title should be concise, not your entire question.

Comment: @nikc ok, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Brian Glaz its formatted properly - sample posted

Comment: @chromedude: It's not about what *I* want. A properly written (with lots of love and attention ;-) question is more likely to attract the attention it deserves. Think of titling as describing/summarizing your use case. Also, your question is not only for you, by asking a question you potentially create useful content for others. (I.e. a title should stand out in a search result view.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the same code you posted i get a nice formatted result

```
file_put_contents( 'tmp.tmp',
'"lorem","ipsum","dolor","sit","amet","consectetuer","adipiscing","elit","sed ","diam","nonummy",
"1lorem","1ipsum","1dolor","1sit","amet","consectetuer","adipiscing","elit","sed ","diam","nonummy",
');

$handle = fopen("tmp.tmp", "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 5000, ",", '"')) !== FALSE) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "<pre>";
}
```

I get:

Array
(
    [0] => lorem
    [1] => ipsum
    [2] => dolor
    [3] => sit
    [4] => amet
    [5] => consectetuer
    [6] => adipiscing
    [7] => elit
    [8] => sed 
    [9] => diam
    [10] => nonummy
    [11] => 
)

You're probaly doing something wrong somewhere else, and not noticing it.

Comment: ah... now I see what I was doing - apparently one version of the file I was using was not formatted that way. weird. thanks though.